# Executing crons in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to execute a cron in symfony (version 1.4.8).

I am trying to use tasks through command: `php symfony generate:task taskName`.

The task generated through this is stored in `lib/task` directory and it has access to all my outer 'lib' files. I also want my other lib folders i.e. the libraries present in apps also to be accessible in this task. how can I do that?

And when do we set `$namespace` in the task as 'project' and as 'application'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do use the following within the crontab

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/yourproject/symfony namespace:task --param=value
```

You will need to change `/usr/bin/php` to match your path to the PHP executable and `/var/www/yourproject` to match your project directory

The `namespace` and `task` should be whatever you have configured within your task :

```
$this->namespace = 'mynamespace';
$this->name = 'mytaskname';
```

here for example the namespace is `mynamespace` and the taskname is `mytaskname`

The following is the contents of a default `autoload.yml` showing which files are autoloaded by default :

```
autoload:
  # project
  project:
    name:           project
    path:           %SF_LIB_DIR%
    recursive:      true
    exclude:        [model, symfony, vendor]

  project_model:
    name:           project model
    path:           %SF_LIB_DIR%/model
    recursive:      true

  # application
  application:
    name:           application
    path:           %SF_APP_LIB_DIR%
    recursive:      true

  modules:
    name:           module
    path:           %SF_APP_DIR%/modules/*/lib
    prefix:         1
    recursive:      true
```

Comment: @user1085195 anything ... whatever the task has been setup to accept - could be `--env=prod` or `--application=frontend`

Comment: I get the error---> "There are no tasks defined in the "namespace" namespace."

Comment: @user1085195 `namespace` should be the namespace of the task - so `doctrine` for example - whatever you configured within the task

Comment: moreover, i want to include all the lib directories in this task, including the ones in the apps folder, how can that be done?

Comment: @user1085195 most are autoloaded by default - see the `autoload.yml` file in your symfony folder

Comment: @user1085195 you won't be able to access files that are in your `app` folder. If you want some method being accessible through your task, you should put them in a dedicated lib inside the `lib` folder.